# Azure Function Apps scalability metrics and terminology for Premium tier

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-app-service-plans

I'm trying to better understand the scalability behavior of my Premium function apps but I'm confused regarding terminology. Specifically I was trying to understand how many "servers" and how many "containers" of my app are running, but I can't be sure what these metrics precisely are:

- AppRoleInstance
- HostInstanceId
- ProcessId

At first I thought a "Host" would be close to a *VM* and an "Instance" would be close to a *container*, but according to what I see that might be actually the other way around. And the `dcount` of ProcessId varies between 1 & 2 on a Always Available Function App with minimum 3 so I can't really understand what this process-id is. The AppRoleInstance and the HostInstanceId are matching most of the time except for some "host" spikes. For reference the query I'm using is similar to this:

```
AppTraces
| where AppRoleName = <function-app-name>
| summarize
    dcount(tostring(AppRoleInstance)),
    dcount(tostring(Properties.HostInstanceId)),
    dcount(tostring(Properties.ProcessId))
  by bin(TimeGenerated, 1h)
| render timechart
```

Answer (score 0):

> And the `dcount` of ProcessId varies between 1 & 2 on a Always Available Function App with minimum 3 so I can't really understand what this process-id is.

Process Id gets assigned in Kudu site as soon as host is initiated for a function.

- You can verify the same by navigating to Advanced Tools.

[image]

- **w3wp.exe** handler gets activated when the function gets triggered and it stays active as long as that job host is active.

[image]

[image]

- If the function app is idle for 20mins then the Job host stops and you will no longer see **w3wp.exe**.

[image]

[image]

- When you will trigger the function or any activity is detected then a new host will be initialized with a new process id.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- **AppRoleInstance** represents the number of Function App instances running at a time and each instance acts as a container which is running in a server.
- **HostInstanceId**  represents number of servers hosting for your function app.
- **Process Id** represents the number of processes running in a container. In a Function App, each container can have a single process but if you are using Always On hosting plan then you can see multiple processes running.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I updated the question to clarify this is Premium tier Function Apps. What's strange is that I made a change a week ago that dropped the number of HostInstanceIds from 20 to 3, and if this represents the number or servers I'd expect to see an equal drop in vCPU Duration costs, but I actually saw an increase in the cost. Would you have any insights on what could potentially explain this scenario?

Comment: BTW here Advanced Tools > Go shows me a different UI: at the top it does not say Kudu but "Azure App Services" and tabs are Environment, SSH, Bash and Log Stream (no process explorer).

Comment: @Renan I have created a Premium plan function app and can see process explorer in kudu as given in my answer. If you are using Premium plan then you should be able to see too

Comment: I'm using Elastic Premium Plan, could this be the reason for the difference in "Kudu" interface?

Comment: @Renan I can see Process explorer in Elastic premium plan too